# Problem with the redirection: Twitter API Oauth

Tags: php, javascript, twitter, oauth

I'm testing the twitter API (with OAuth) and I have a little problem, I wonder if anyone knows how to fix it, the situation is that at the time I do this (in my redirect.php):

```
$ Url = $ connection-> getAuthorizeURL ($ token);
header ("Location: $ url");
```

The request go to twitter, and it's authenticated, but I this return my application back to the home page, and I want to do it in the page I'm doing the OAuth.

Does anyone know the solution?

In short, when users log in, I want the application return it to the same page, not the beginning.

Ah! When I do the log out, all is correct... because I do this (in my clearsessions.php):

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
$redireccion = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
header("Location: $redireccion");
```

My problem is in the "log in" :-)

Thanks!

Ehm... 
You can try it here: http://www.joanballestermoragues.com/oauth/test.php
As you can see, the login in twitter redirect to http://www.joanballestermoragues.com/oauth/ and I want to redirect to: http://www.joanballestermoragues.com/oauth/test.php

PS: Ah, any can say... "make an index.php and that's all", but no, because this is for another application, it's only a test and I need to do it in another pages than "index" :-)

Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set your callback URL in your Twitter connection settings and that should fix it.  Otherwise, make sure you set the oauth_callback value when requesting the token before you redirect the user to Twitter.

Comment: Is dynamic... ;-)
In this example is "test.php" but this will be dynamic!

Comment: Did you set the oauth_callback value when requesting the token before you redirected the user to Twitter?  Do you have the settings on twitter correct (eg browser for application mode, and a non-blank default value for Callback URL)?

Comment: I don't understand your first question, but I think no (how can I do this?). 
The second one: Browser and non-blank default value for callback. Yes I have this OK. I'm going to write the code that you have mention

Answer (score 0):

In the class TwitterOAuth, I've seen this construct:

```
  function __construct($consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $oauth_token = NULL, $oauth_token_secret = NULL) {
    $this->sha1_method = new OAuthSignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1();
    $this->consumer = new OAuthConsumer($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
    if (!empty($oauth_token) && !empty($oauth_token_secret)) {
      $this->token = new OAuthConsumer($oauth_token, $oauth_token_secret);
    } else {
      $this->token = NULL;
    }
  }
```

And, this line:

```
$this->consumer = new OAuthConsumer($consumer_key, $consumer_secret);
```

The method OAuthConsumer() can have another parameter, "$callback_url" (default value is NULL).

May be the solution? I can pass another parameter in this moment. I can put the actual URL... Well I can try it later.